# Rspec/Capybara`js: true` issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, multi-tenant

I use Rspec/Capybara in my Rails app. Within one feature test I have `js: true` option to check for modal and click button in it. Was working fine until the moment I added `apartment` gem for multi-tenancy and PosgreSQL schemas.

Now it is not finding button for calling modal. I am event not sure It is logged properly (`binding.pry` not working in tests with `js` correctly).
I thought this is DatabaseCleaner issue, but my config seems to be correct (see below).

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
 end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Apartment::Tenant.reset
  end
end
```

What options could be suggested to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/wiki/Testing-Your-Application)'s an example of RSpec configuration for `Apartment`. Please pay attention to the part where the schema is dropped.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    # Clean all tables to start
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    # Use transactions for tests
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    # Truncating doesn't drop schemas, ensure we're clean here, app *may not* exist
    Apartment::Tenant.drop('app') rescue nil
    # Create the default tenant for our tests
    Company.create!(name: 'Influitive Corp.', subdomain: 'app')
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    # Start transaction for this test
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    # Switch into the default tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.switch! 'app'
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    # Reset tentant back to `public`
    Apartment::Tenant.reset
    # Rollback transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Also you can rewrite a portion of `DatabaseCleaner` configuration to be a bit shorter

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for those improved settings. Though, I still am not able to make tests pass. I even wrote more simple test  to check for presence or text "Help" (which is on every page, no matter is user logged or no), it fails as well. Seems like in `feature "AdminSpec", type: :feature, js: true do` page is not rendered as it should.

Comment: Well go ahead and debug what get's rendered. Maybe you get a helpful error message.

Comment: I added `save_and_open_page` comand and it shows that capybara seems nothing, I get compleately blank page, no errors, etc. And it is custom, App-wide page `/help`. When I remove `js: true` from my feature, page is rendered as it should be

Comment: Have you dumped the whole contents (as in html code) of page?

Comment: Yes.
Actually I figured out the reason of that, will add answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the real reason of the `js: true` issue. 
The thing is that I had `config.block_unknown_url` in my "capybara.rb".
For testing multi-tenancy I use `lvh.me` domain, so I needed to add `config.allow_url("*.lvh.me")` to "capybara.rb" file to fix broken `js: true` stuff.